# Libgit2sharp conflict get theirs/ours/base files content

Tags: libgit2sharp

I use Libgit2sharp and I want to solve a conflict.
In the class "Conflict" I have 3 IndexEntry properties (Ancestor, Ours, Theirs)
Each of them has the property "Path" that point to the same file.

I want to lanch the TortoiseGitMerge tool and I want to generate the base/ours/theirs/ files...

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `ConflictCollection` from the `Index`:

```
var conflicts = repository.Index.Conflicts;
```

Then get the conflict for a particular file:

```
var conflict = conflicts["Foo.cs"];
```

Then you can get the `IndexEntry` for each side of the conflict:

```
var ancestor = conflict.Ancestor;
var ours = conflict.Ours;
var theirs = conflict.Theirs;
```

With the index entry, you can get the objects:

```
var ancestorBlob = (ancestor != null) ? repository.Lookup(ancestor.Id) : null;
var ourBlob = (ours != null) ? repository.Lookup(ours.Id) : null;
var theirBlob = (theirs != null) ? repository.Lookup(theirs.Id) : null;
```

And you can get a stream for contents of each side:

```
var ancestorStream = (ancestor != null) ? ancestorBlob.GetContentStream(new FilteringOptions(ancestor.Name));
var ourStream = (ours != null) ? ourBlob.GetContentStream(new FilteringOptions(ours.Name));
var theirStream = (theirs != null) ? theirBlob.GetContentStream(new FilteringOptions(theirs.Name));
```

Then you can write each file - remember that a conflict may have three different paths, if the file was renamed in each side, and you should inspect the `Conflict.Name` for each.  For example, to write one of the sides to disk:

```
using (var ancestorOutputStream = File.Create(ancestor.Name + ".orig"))
{
    ancestorStream.CopyTo(ancestorOutputStream);
}
```

Comment: The only difference was that I used a foreach to process conflicts and then for each conflict I got the file name from Ours.Path of the conflict, because of this path is the same in all properties (Ours, Theirs, Base)

Comment: @Sergiu That's not guaranteed - if one of the files was renamed, the paths can be different.

Comment: Hm... then... How to obtain the file name?

Comment: Sorry!  The filename is in the conflict, it's `Conflict.Name`.  You can see that illustrated above, passing it to the `FilteringOptions`.

Comment: Yes it is - thanks - I updated my answer to note that.